# OnRequest tab soapUI error

Tags: java, groovy, soapui

On running this below groovy script in OnRequest script tab of a soapUI mock request I get the below error

`mockRunner.returnFile(mockRequest.httpResponse, new File(projectDir,"xmlresponse.xml"))
return new com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockResult(mockRequest)`

```
    ERROR:An error occurred [groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockRunner.returnFile() is applicable for argument types: (org.mortbay.jetty.Response, java.io.File) values: [HTTP/1.1 200 

, C:\UXX\XXXX\AAAAA\xmlresponse.xml]], see error log for details
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Edited:

I tried your suggestion but getting this error. 
`You cannot create an instance from the abstract interface.` Then I tried a different way , found out by searching web.

```
def response = mockRequest.httpResponse
File file = new File("C:/Users/xx/xx/xxx/xmlresponse.xml")
FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);
response.setStatus( HttpServletResponse.SC_OK )
long length = file.length();
response.setContentType("application/xml;charset=utf-8" );
Tools.readAndWrite( fin, length, response.getOutputStream() );
fin.close();
return new com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockResult(mockRequest)
```

But the issue with this is I am getting the xml response in the Json and raw tab of response side. When I set content as xml like this  `response.setContentType("application/xml;charset=utf-8" )` in above code , it doesnt give anything in json and xml tab but gives the response with xml content in raw tab. How do I get xml content back  in xml tab?

Comment: Though I am still getting the error, but found a way to do what I wanted to achieve with a new feature, "Rest Mocking" , in soapUI 5.0.0. But  if someone has an idea about this error, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was having the exact same issue with my mock REST request / response in Soap UI 5

The other answer is correct in theory, creating a response in a groovy script does in fact work. However, there was some issue with the Groovy OnRequest script. 
Here's the code segment I used to create a valid XML response (courtesy of [DivxYoda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1919156/divxyoda) from this question [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21850227/mock-rest-service-response-json-and-xml-using-soapui)):

```
com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockResult mockResult = new com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockResult(mockRequest)

def httpResponse = mockRequest.httpResponse
httpResponse.setContentType("application/xml;charset=utf-8")
httpResponse.writer << "<root><user>ABC</user></root>"
httpResponse.status = 200
return mockResult
```

Tested, and works great for me!

Comment: Thanks!  I can get xml content back in xml tab with the above code.

Answer (score 1):

The `com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.WsdlMockRunner.returnFile()` function accepts

```
javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse

and File
```

instead of `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse` you are sending `org.mortbay.jetty.Response`. To send a `javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse` value you could do something like this..

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

def response = new HttpServletResponse();

response.setStatus(200)
response.setContentType("text/xml;charset=UTF-8");
```

Link: [Values not passing from TextBox to Servlet File](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21857004/1788964)

and then pass the response variable to the `returnFile()` function.

**Note**: The code is untested!

Comment: I edited the post above based on your suggestion and new finding, since it wouldn't fit here.